# Alternative to flex-flow:column for older browsers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given a set of children I need to alternate between two sets of stacking as illustrated in the image below.

[image]

I was able to achieve this stacking using `flex-flow: column`. Since it is not supported in IE9, is there a way to achieve this stacking without flex box for older browsers?

```css
.box {
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 5px;
}
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 70px;    
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is with CSS multiple columns. But [support for this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) is roughly the same as flex box. So I think you're out of luck.

Comment: the old hack with float and fixed height

Comment: use js / jquery: http://osvaldas.info/responsive-equal-height-blocks

Comment: @GiacomoPaita I was hoping to avoid progrmmatic control of the layout, but thanks. Will give it a try.

Comment: @madalinivascu I can live with fixed height children. Do you have an implementation somewhere I can refer to?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m5jk8wko/

Comment: Thanks @madalinivascu The fiddle shows box 3 below box 1. I am trying to achieve the second layout in the image which is box 2 below box 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack using negative margin:

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 5px;
    width:100px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}
.container {
    height: 70px; 
    width:225px;
}
.container div:nth-child(1) {
    color:red;
    float: left;

}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
    color:red;
    float: left;
        clear: both;
}
.container div:nth-child(3) {
    color:red;
    float: right;
    margin-top:-107px;

}
.container div:nth-child(4) {
    color:red;
    float: right;
      clear: both;
      margin-top:-107px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m5jk8wko/1/